# Asp.Net Control.ClientID returns object instead of string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Sometimes in asp.net, the Control.ClientID returns the whole Control object instead of the ClientID string. I haven't paid too much attention to it up until now as I could just fish it out client side with ClientID.Id. But now I need to pass the ID of an iframe and IE won't let me pass the iframe object so I have to get the string of the ID this time.

The iframe:

```
<iframe ID="VideoFrame" runat="server" class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" ></iframe>

<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="YouTubeScript" />
```

The Codebehind:

```
YouTubeScript.Text = @"
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(function() {
                    " + Helpers.CallJavascriptFunction("InitYoutubeVideo", VideoFrame.ClientID) + @"
                });
            </script>
        ";
```

**Update/Answer**
I need to wrap `VideoFrame.ClientID` in quotation marks so that javascript/jquery recognises it as a string. Otherwise it sees the id and converts it into the html object belonging to that id.

Comment: ClientID is a string property so that's technically not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to mix javascript and inline aspnet code somehow. it should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Helpers.CallJavascriptFunction("InitYoutubeVideo", "<%= VideoFrame.ClientID %>");
</script>
```

Comment: I've updated my codebehind to show the js snippet is the text for an asp literal

Comment: Ah, in that case it would make sense. However as @hardkoded already mentioned, the code will not send the object itself. It would make more sense if you do something wrong inside the `InitYoutubeVideo` function.

Comment: normally it would just send the ClientID but for some reason it's sending the whole control. I put in a console.log before the Helpers call and it logged the iframe itself

Comment: What exactly is happening in `CallJavascriptFunction`?

Comment: it's just a helper so I don't have to concatonate a load of stuff to write a js function literal string. Anyway, I found the issue and edited my question to include it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Use the client ID properly:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        InitYoutubeVideo('<%=VideoFrame.ClientID%>');
    });
</script>
```

Or make the client id static:

```
<iframe ID="VideoFrame" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" ></iframe>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        InitYoutubeVideo('VideoFrame');
    });
</script>
```